# Scheduling torrents in Transmission - using WD My Cloud

Tags: downloads, transmission

is there a way that I can Schedule downloads in the Transmission app to take place only during certain hours of the day.

For example: from 19:00 - 08:00
That way when I use my internet the most it isn't being used up by downloads.

Answer (score 0):

It is called "turtle mode"

Transmission v1.72+ lets you limit DL/UL speeds by time of day and has a speed limit mode you can click.

---

[From the manual](http://www.transmissionbt.com/help/gtk/2.3x/html/preferences.html)

> **Temporary Speed Limits**
>
> Temporary speed limits -- often called "turtle mode" -- are a second
> set of upload and download limits that can be set to run on a schedule
> and can also be toggled manually. Scheduled use is helpful if your ISP
> has different bandwidth caps on evenings or weekends. Manual use is
> helpful as a single-click way to quickly give other applications more
> bandwidth. You can toggle turtle mode manually by clicking the turtle
> button in the lower left corner of Transmission's main window.
>
> - The Temporary download speed is the download speed limit enforced when turtle mode is active.
> - The Temporary upload speed is the upload speed limit enforced when turtle mode is active.
> - With Scheduled times, you can tell Transmission when to automatically enable and disable turtle mode.

So yes, in the preferences, speed tab you can set time and on what days turtle mode needs to be active or inactive and with what speeds turtle mode should work at.

[image]